# Ranking based on product features

Tags: java, mysql, ranking

I have the following tables in a `mysql` database:

1. products

   - product_id
   - product_name
   - product_catagory_id_fk
2. product_features

   - feature_id
   - product_id_fk
   - feature_name

I need to add ranking facility to the products depending on their features,

The ranking would start from 1 to 100 for example depending on the features of the product,

Giving each feature a "weight" and defining a product's overall "score" to be the sum of its component features,

Weights would be one way of accomplishing this,

Eventually it will be used to compare products in the same category,

Can you please suggest the following:

- What new tables do I need to add
- What columns do I need to add to the existing tables
- How to calculate the ranking to associate to the tables

All help would be appreciated

Comment: This seems very interesting indeed, let's see what would be the answer

Comment: Please define what you mean by a "*ranking facility*" in terms of the functionality it must provide.  For example, just giving each feature a "weight" and defining a product's overall "score" to be the sum of its component features' weights would be one way of accomplishing this... but whether that delivers the functionality you require is completely unclear.

Comment: @eggyal yes that's really what I need, can you please explain more in an answer

Comment: @Sufian what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

1. Give each feature a weight:

   ```sql
   ALTER TABLE product_features ADD COLUMN weight INT;
   UPDATE product_features SET weight = ? WHERE feature_id = ?; -- and repeat
   ```
2. Select products (joined with their features and then grouped), sorted by total score:

   ```sql
   SELECT   p.*, SUM(f.weight) AS score
   FROM     products p
       JOIN product_features f ON f.product_id_fk = p.product_id
   GROUP BY p.product_id
   ORDER BY score DESC
   ```
3. Or to obtain the rank of a specific product:

   ```sql
   SELECT 1+COUNT(*) AS rank FROM (
     SELECT   NULL
     FROM     product_features
     GROUP BY product_id_fk
     HAVING   SUM(weight) > (
                SELECT SUM(weight)
                FROM   product_features
                WHERE  product_id_fk = ?   -- your product_id here
              )
   ) t
   ```

Comment: could you expand more please and explain more, because I need more information

Comment: @HumanBeing: What more information do you need?

Comment: how ranking is done, how weight is calculated?

Comment: @HumanBeing: I thought you were intending to give each feature a weight (manually)?  And ranking is done by sorting by the `score` of each product, i.e. the sum of its component features' weights.

Comment: ok, each feature has a weight, how weight is defined, percentage, number to be added to the other weights then how to calculate the rank?

Comment: @HumanBeing: Weights can be whatever metric/unit you want, provided that they can simply be summed to produce an overall score for each product (if you have a different requirement, please do say).  As for "*calculating the rank*", the resultset from #2 will be in sorted order... I have updated with a query that returns only the rank of a specific product, should that have been what you were after?

Comment: yes sort of: but how to calculate the weights' sum et the end to convert it to a ranking

Comment: @HumanBeing: `SUM(weight)` as shown in my answer?

Comment: [ PLUS ONE ] yep like I guessed

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create a separate table for **features** with associated weight like **Small** is having weight 1, **Medium** is having weight 2, **Large** is having weight 3 and so on.

So now **features** table would be something like

```
features
  - feature_id
  - feature_name
  - feature_weight
```

Create a separate table for **product_feature_associations**

```
product_feature_associations
  - product_id_fk
  - feature_id_fk
```

You can also add a new column **product_ranking** in **products** table in order to avoid mass calculation during product list fetching, each time you associate a new feature to any product, update this **product_ranking** field by calculating the associated weight. It will save your lots of time but you need to keep in track all actions into **product_feature_associations** table, like you have to keep track of add, edit, delete actions on **product_feature_associations** table and update the **product_ranking** accordingly.

Comment: You assume here that different products share common features—which wasn't indicated in the question.

Comment: In that case it would be hard to put a weight for each individual feature, if you have 1 million products or more.

Comment: Perhaps.  But now we're just speculating over the OP's requirements.  You may well be right—I'm certainly not discounting it—I'm just observing that this goes beyond the question as currently posed.

Comment: Thanks @eggyal, but I put an optimal solution for future perspective as well.

Comment: @HumanBeing: I assumed that different products will share common features. Is it Ok?

Comment: They may have common features, but the weight of that specific feature differs according to the product, and one more thing: how to calculate the weights' sum et the end to convert it to a ranking

Comment: @Human Being: So, the weight of the specific feature would be differ even if theu co related to multiple products?

Comment: @HumanBeing: In that case there will be additional change into **product_feature_associations** table like you have to add **weight** column in this table rather than **features** table.

Comment: how to calculate the weights' sum et the end to convert it to a ranking

Comment: @HumanBeing: Lets say you have a product **Mobile Phone** and you have added 3 features Long life Battery, Slick design and Large Screen size having weight 3,5,7 so for every time you added a feature for this product you have to update the value into **product_ranking** column in **products** table. Now overall ranking of product **Mobile Phone** is (3+5+7 = 15). Is it OK?

Comment: [PLUS ONE] sort of

Comment: @HumanBeing: Is this answer helpful to you?

Comment: yes thanks I am trying to implement the whole idea